# Espresso perform and check doesn't work with Hilt+Navigation test

Tags: android, navigation, android-espresso, android-testing, android-architecture-navigation

My Test Code works with Navigation. But, click, type, etc events are not working. And also, the check() method isn't called.

I tried with running it inside runOnUiThread too. But still doesn't work. The login fragment is opened but no typing event causes.

How can I solve this issue?

My test code is below.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@HiltAndroidTest
class LoginFragmentTest {
    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun test() {
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<LoginFragment>(null, R.style.ThemeDrugDelivery) {

            // Create a NavController and set the NavController property on the fragment
            assertNotNull(requireActivity())
            val navController = TestNavHostController(requireActivity())
            requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_login)
            }
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)

            requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                onView(withId(R.id.acet_email)).perform(typeText("helloworld"))
                onView(withId(R.id.acet_email)).check(matches(withText("helloworld")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to consider navigation. When the Activity is created the host nav will be shown and I could access the views right away without any settings.

Just like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@HiltAndroidTest
class LoginActivityTest {
    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun typeLoginInfo() {
        val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(LoginActivity::class.java)
        onView(withId(R.id.acet_email))
            .perform(typeText("helloworld"))
            .check(matches(withText("helloworld")))
        onView(withId(R.id.acet_password)).perform(typeText("helloworld"))
            .check(matches(withText("helloworld")))
    }
}
```

But when I do navigate to other fragments.

```
@MediumTest
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NavControllerTest {
    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun testLoginFragmentToJoinFragment() {
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<LoginFragment>(null,
            R.style.CustomTheme) {
            // Create a NavController and set the NavController property on the fragment
            assertNotNull(requireActivity())
            val navController = TestNavHostController(requireActivity())
            requireActivity().runOnUiThread { navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_login) }
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)

            // Then navigate
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_joinFragment)
            val destination = navController.currentDestination
            assertNotNull(destination)
            assertEquals(destination!!.id, R.id.joinFragment)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testLoginFragmentToFindFragment() {
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<LoginFragment>(null,
            R.style.CustomTheme) {

            // Create a NavController and set the NavController property on the fragment
            assertNotNull(requireActivity())
            val navController = TestNavHostController(requireActivity())
            requireActivity().runOnUiThread { navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_login) }
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)

            // Then navigate
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_findFragment)
            val destination = navController.currentDestination
            assertNotNull(destination)
            assertEquals(destination!!.id, R.id.findFragment)
        }
    }
}
```